# Colors and Shapes in geom_point legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, legend, geom-point

Hi there I have a very simple problem I think, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Basically, I have a `geom_point` plot where I have two approaches used and I wish to both differentiate shapes and colors for each of the two. At first it seems to be working correctly; however, once I get to the *legend* something weird happens...

It looks like R cannot recognize the `guides` argument and, specifically, I cannot set my legend title to something I chose neither I can move it on top of the legend itself. Additionally, it appears R picks up the `geom_label_repel` as the icons shown in the legend...

If there is a fix to this, any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

*See below* for the plot and the code
[image]

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)

excel_variants <- read_excel("/path/to/papuan_samples_variant-plot.xlsx", 2)

df_variants <- data.frame(excel_variants)

df_variants$sample <- factor(df_variants$sample, levels=c('6103675', '6103673', '6103671'))
#df_variants$approach <- factor(df_variants$approach, levels=c('filtered', 'personalized'))

### PLOT THE DATA
plot <- 
  
  ggplot(df_variants, aes(x=sample, y=value, color=approach, shape=approach)) + geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15), size=2) +
  
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c('filtered'=15, 'personalized'=16)) + scale_color_manual(values=brewer.pal(11, "PRGn")[c(3, 9)]) + 
  ggtitle("SVs metrics") + guides(values=guide_legend(title='graph used', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5)) + 
  coord_flip()
plot

plot + geom_label_repel(aes(label=labels),
                 box.padding  = 0.5, 
                 point.padding = 0,
                 segment.color = 'grey50')
```

**EDIT:** data frame structure

```
structure(list(sample = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("6103675", 
"6103673", "6103671"), class = "factor"), approach = c("personalized", 
"personalized", "personalized", "filtered", "filtered", "filtered", 
"personalized", "personalized", "personalized", "filtered", "filtered", 
"filtered", "personalized", "personalized", "personalized", "filtered", 
"filtered", "filtered"), value = c(0.997, 0.5088, 0.6737, 0.9997, 
0.3329, 0.4995, 0.9973, 0.5174, 0.6814, 0.9998, 0.338, 0.5052, 
0.9971, 0.5031, 0.6688, 0.9999, 0.3335, 0.5001), labels = c("precision", 
"recall", "F1", "precision", "recall", "F1", "precision", "recall", 
"F1", "precision", "recall", "F1", "precision", "recall", "F1", 
"precision", "recall", "F1")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to assign `name` parameter in your `scale_*()` to add names.

Try to add `theme(legend.position = "top")` to set legend position.

Add `show.legend = F` to `geom_label_repel()` call to remove letters from legend:

```
plot <- 
  
  ggplot(df_variants, aes(x=sample, y=value, color=approach, shape=approach)) + geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15), size=2) +
  
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c('filtered'=15, 'personalized'=16), name = "My Legend") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=brewer.pal(11, "PRGn")[c(3, 9)], name = "My Legend") + 
  ggtitle("SVs metrics") + guides(values=guide_legend(title='graph used', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5)) + 
  coord_flip()


plot + geom_label_repel(aes(label=labels),
                        box.padding  = 0.5, 
                        point.padding = 0,
                        segment.color = 'grey50', 
                        show.legend = F)+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

**Note** that the I could not debug the script as there was no data provided in your question. Please do so calling `dput(yourDataFrame)` and provide the result in your future questions.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It actually fixed the icon showed in the legend. I was experimenting a bit since I couldn't figure out how to change the actual legend title and its positioning. Whether possible, that would be the last thing I'm interested in doing. Also, I added the output of `dput(myDataFrame)`. Thanks again!

Comment: I figured out after few extra trials, for the name of the legend displayed on screen was easy (sorry for the stupid question). Instead, the position for the legend title required to swap the "values" attribute in the `guides` argument with "shape so that the code could catch the actual associated legend.